# Creating a fadeOut and fadeIn in sequence using jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I would like my ".elliot" tag to fade in after ".skinner" fades out.  My current scripts are not working properly.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".skinner").fadeOut("fast", function () {})
    }, 500)
})


jQuery(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".elliot").fadeIn("slow", function () {})
    }, 1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete handler on fadeOut.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(".skinner").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $(".elliot").fadeIn("slow")
    } , 500)
})
```